# Autofill,save password,spellcheck,Application cache in WkWebview

Tags: ios, swift, spell-checking, autofill, wkwebview

I am looking for a way to do AutoFill,SavePassword and Spellcheck in WkWebView

AFAIK

SpellCheck(`spellcheck="true"`),Autocomplete(`'autocomplete','off'`) can be done by specifying HTML Attributes

SavePassword and Autofill can be worked around using `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` and *NSUserDefaults*

I have an webapp which is going to be loaded in WkWebView and I'd like to facilitate SavePassword,AutoFill and Spellcheck using WkWebView itself.

Does WkWebView provide any interface to directly deal with these ?

Any suggestions are appreciated !

Comment: Any update on that ?

Answer (score 1):

While this DOES allow autofill/keychain to fill credentials on a properly set-up trusted domain through wkwebview, it still does not allow the SAVE/STORAGE of user/pass upon entry. This behavior is strange - meaning one can use their web credentials to sign into an app which also includes this domain as trusted, but the user cannot save their user/pass FROM the app/wkwebview despite it being trusted. There is no documentation from Apple explaining this discrepancy - and many have the same issue.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31259229)

Comment: The question asks about implementing three features associated with built-in browser functionality. AutoFill is supported, but SavePassword is not according to my experience described above. While I cannot answer the entire question, it really is a question with three parts; two of which I have addressed.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Apple doesn't allow us to use Autofill in WKWebview because the app may steal your information.

Comment: But , if apple wants they could prompt for user permission every time the app is trying to access Autofill

Answer (score 0):

> ## Enable Password AutoFill
>
> Password AutoFill uses heuristics to determine when the user logs in or creates new passwords, and automatically provides the password QuickType bar. These heuristics give users some Password AutoFill support in most apps, even if those apps haven’t been updated to support AutoFill. However, to provide the best user experience and ensure your app fully supports Password AutoFill, perform the following steps:
>
> - Set up your app’s associated domains. To learn how to set up your app’s associated domains, see Supporting Associated Domains.
> - Set the correct AutoFill type on relevant text fields. For an iOS app, see Enabling Password AutoFill on a Text Input View. For a web app, see Enabling Password AutoFill on an HTML Input Element.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill